# error Property [xxx] does not exist on this collection instance, laravel

Tags: laravel

tengo un problema con laravel 8... Tengo una funcion en mi controlador que me trae datos de 2 tablas relacionadas:

```
public function show($id){
        $ingreso = DB::table('asignacion_materials as a')
        ->join('tecnicos as t', 'a.tecnico_id', '=', 't.id')
        ->join('servicios as s', 's.id', '=', 't.servicio_id')
        ->join('personals as p', 'a.usuario_id', '=', 'p.id')
        ->select('a.id','a.fecha_asignacion', 'a.tipo', 'a.num_guia_despacho', 'a.observaciones', 's.servicio', 't.nombre_primario', 't.ape_pat', 't.num_doc', 'p.nombre_primario')
        ->where('a.id', '=', $id)
        ->first();

        $detalle = DB::table('det_asignacion_materials as d')
        //->join('bodegas as b', 'd.bodega_id', '=', 'b.id')
        ->join('materials as m', 'd.material_id', '=', 'm.id')
        ->join('asignacion_materials as am', 'd.asignacion_material_id', '=', 'am.id')
        ->join('bodegas as b', 'd.bodega_id', '=', 'b.id')
        ->select('m.detalle', 'd.cantidad', 'b.nombre_bodega')
        ->where('d.asignacion_material_id', '=', $id)
        ->get();

        return view('persona.logistica.asignacion.show', ['dets' => $detalle, 'ingreso' =>$ingreso]);
```

en mi vista(blade) muestro los datos todos ok hasta que debo mostrar el campo $dets->nombre_bodega me arroja el error: Property [nombre_bodega] does not exist on this collection instance y segun veo en la funcion estaria bien...

No se que puedo estar haciendo mal

Saludos a todos

Comment: Como lo muestras en tu blade, podrías colocar esa parte del código

Comment: hola, mira en una tabla recorro asi:

Comment: por favor agrega la o las iteraciones que haces en el blade

Comment: Lo que pasa es que usas `get`, por lo cual mandas una coleccion, tendrias que iterar para que te muestre el resultado, ahora si solo es un dato, deberias colocar como lo hiciste arriba con un `first()`, deberia solucionarlo

Comment: felipe creo que con lo que me comentas se soluciono! gracias